# Entity Framework 6 Code First int Identity column value is zero for first row

Tags: c#, sql-server, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

After the first execution of the update-database command to populate the database with seed data:

Found that all int Id columns started with zero (0) rather than the expected one (1).

Added the following 2 lines of code for each entity/table to the top of the Seed method in Configuration.cs:

[Note: Because of the foreign key constraints, I deleted all rows in descendent tables, and then worked my way up the ancestral chain.]

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("delete from Widgets");
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DBCC CHECKIDENT ('Widgets', RESEED, 0)");
```

Then, I reran update-database, and all of the int Id columns started with one (1).

If I drop the database, run/add the initial migration and then run update-database, all of the int Id columns start with zero (0).

It is as if the `DBCC CHECKIDENT ('Widgets', RESEED, 0)` SQL statements are not being executed the first time that the Seed method is run.

Also, if there is no seed data for an entity/table, it does not matter how many times the update-database command is run, the first time a row is added to the empty table, the Id will be zero (0).

Possibly, is there a way to specify the initial seed value for int Identity columns in the override `OnModelCreating` method of `IdentityModels.cs`?

**Update:**

1. Changed: `DBCC CHECKIDENT ('Table', RESEED, 0)` to `DBCC CHECKIDENT ('Table', RESEED, 1)` in Configuration.cs.
2. Deleted the database.
3. Executed: `update-database -TargetMigration Initial` (Result is all int Ids start with 1.)
4. Executing `update-database` to reset the database. (Result is all int Ids start with 2, no matter how many times you run `update-database`.)

Comment: Your seed method needs to be: context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DBCC CHECKIDENT ('Widgets', RESEED, 1)");

Comment: I first used 1, and the first rows had Id=2, when I ran update-database. So, I changed it to 0.

Comment: If you've had things in a transaction and tried to insert into an identity and rolled back - then you will see this sort of behaviour.  I'd be curious and switch some SQL Profiling on to see if anything unusual is happening (without sounding patronising) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx.  Look for TSQL commands.

Comment: Thank you @anders-abel for your comment.Well, when I migrate the app to Azure, I want the database seeding to have int Ids starting at one (1), so I changed the RESEED statements in Configuration.cs to be "RESEED, 1)"

Comment: I mean, thank you @Andez for your comment. Now, if I want to reset the local development copy of the app database by running update-database, I will just have to live with int Ids starting at two (2).

Comment: Thank you, @Dustin_00. The only way I am able to get the int Ids to start at one (1) again is to delete the (local copy of the) database and then run update-database -TargetMigration Initial.

Answer (score 0):

Your concrete migration class should look "something" like the following:

```
public class 201707132034165_MyAwesomeDbInitial : DbMigration
{
    #region <Methods>

    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.HasOverdrive",
            c => new
            {
                HasOverdriveId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                HasOverdriveValue = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 5)
            })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.HasOverdriveId)
            .Index(t => t.HasOverdriveValue, unique: true, name: "UX_HasOverdrive_AlternateKey");
    }

    // This should is called by your DbConfiguration class
    public void Seed(MyAwesomeDbContext context)
    {
        // DO THIS FIRST !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DBCC CHECKIDENT ('HasOverdrive', RESEED, 0)");

        // LOOKUPS
        SeedHasOverdrive(context);
    }

    private void SeedHasOverdrive(MeasurementContractsDbContext context)
    {
        context.HasOverdrive.AddOrUpdate
        (
            m => m.Id,
            new HasOverdrive { HasOverdriveId = 0, HasOverdriveValue = "No" }, // 0 = FALSE 
            new HasOverdrive { HasOverdriveId = 1, HasOverdriveValue = "Yes" } // 1 = TRUE
        );
    }

    #endregion
}
```